# The relation between irreducible and primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Am I right in thinking that the conventional definition of a prime integer (can only be written as itself times $1$ and has no other factors) is actually the definition for irreducible?

Is it true that this is given because prime and irreducible are equivalent in a ring and it the above definition is so much easier than explaining that a number $p$ is prime if and only if “$p$ divides $ab$” implies either “$p$ divides $a$” or “$p$ divides $b$”.

Why are these equivalent?

Are there any simple examples of numbers that are either prime or irreducible but not both?

Comment: In a ring, we have irreducible elements and prime elements. Every prime element is irreducible, but an irreducible element need not be prime. In the ring $\mathbb Z$ however, an element is a prime element if and only if it is irreducible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The set of integers is Unique Factorization Domain, that is, every element can be uniquely factorized. In UFD, a non-unit element is prime if and only if it is irreducible. So in $\mathbb{Z}$, there is no counterexample.

In $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$, which is a set of elements of the form $a+b\sqrt{-5}$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers, $9$ can be written in two forms,
$$
9=3^2 = (2-\sqrt{-5})(2+\sqrt{-5})
$$
and $3$ divides $(2-\sqrt{-5})(2+\sqrt{-5})$ but does not divide neither $2-\sqrt{-5}$ nor $2+\sqrt{-5}$. So $3$ is not a prime here. You can also see that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not UFD. However, it is an irreducible element. This can be shown by solving the following equation
$$
3=(a+b\sqrt{-5})(c+d\sqrt{-5})
$$
for integers $a,b,c$ and $d$. Long and uninteresting calculation will show that $b=d=0$ and either one of $a$ and $c$ is $1$, and the other one is $3$.

Conversely, in integral domain $R$, being prime always implies that it is an irreducible element. Suppose a prime $p$ is reducible, so there are two non-unit elements $a,b$ such that $p=ab$. Since $p$ divides $ab=p$, by the definition of the primality, $p$ must divide $a$ or $b$. We may assume that $p$ divides $a$, and there is $c\in R$ such that $pc=a$. Thus
$$
p=ab=pcb \implies cb=1
$$
so it contradicts that $b$ is non-unit. The cancellation works because we are working in the integral domain.

Answer (score 4):

You're pretty much right: In a general commutative ring $R$, the property
\begin{align*}
p = ab \Rightarrow a \in R^* \vee b \in R^*
\end{align*}

is called *irreducibility*. *Primality* on the other hand is the property

\begin{align*}
p\mid ab \Rightarrow p\mid a \vee p \mid b.
\end{align*}

If $R$ is a UFD (e.g. $R = \mathbb{Z}$), an element has one of these two properties iff it has the other one, so the two notions coincide. Therefore a prime element in $\mathbb{Z}$ can be defined as a number that is irreducible.

**BUT**: Primality and irreducibility are not, in general, the same: While primes are always irreducible in integral domains, the number $3 \in \mathbb{Z} \hspace{-0.1cm} \left[ \sqrt{-5} \right]$ is an example of an irreducible element which isn't prime.

Comment: Don't you need extra restrictions, i.e. that primes are not units?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Units are excluded from being prime elements by definition.

Comment: Yes, I know.  I am not sure about irreducible elements, though. Of course one wants to get rid of (infinite) products of units, but it's still the case that units cannot be decomposed further (except in cases where vasically every element is a unit).

Answer (score 3):

The definitions are equivalent in a unique factorization domain like $\mathbb Z$. In a non-UFD, there is still a set of prime numbers and a set of irreducible numbers, but they don't overlap completely.

For example, $-37$ is not divisible by any number in $\mathbb Z$ closer to 0 than itself, other than $-1$ and 1. Hence it is irreducible in $\mathbb Z$. But it is also prime, because in any product $ab$ that is divisible by $-37$ we will find that either $a$ or $b$ is a multiple of $-37$, or maybe they both are.

Compare to $74$. That's obviously not prime, and it's not irreducible either, it's reducible. We see that $74 \mid 148$, but if we express 148 as $-4 \times -37$, we see that 74 divides neither the $a$ nor the $b$.

Now let's take a look at an integral domain like $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-70}]$. In that domain, $-37$ is still irreducible, because it's not divisible by any number closer to 0 other than $-1$ and 1.

But now we see that $-37 \mid (2 - \sqrt{-70})(2 + \sqrt{-70})$, yet neither $2 - \sqrt{-70}$ nor $2 + \sqrt{-70}$ is divisible by $-37$. Numbers like 3 and 13 are still irreducible and prime in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-70}]$, though.

As for a number that is prime but not irreducible, consider $\mathbb Z_6$, which consists only of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (addition and multiplication "wrap around" to keep things within the ring). Verify that $$3 = 3^2 = 3^3 = 3^4 = \ldots = 3 \times 5 = 3 \times 5^2 = \ldots$$ but also that the only way to get 3 as a product in this ring is to include 3 at least once as a multiplicand.

P.S. I chose $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-70}]$ rather than $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{78}]$ because even though we have to deal with complex numbers, things are in some ways much simpler.

Comment: **Beware** Your last example is meaningless without any definition of irreducible in rings with zero-divisors. There are various incompatible definitions in use, and what you wrote is false with some common definitions, e.g. see the [paper linked here,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/881819/242) where (Corollary 2.7) idempotents are irreducible $\iff$ prime (note $3 = 3^2,$ i.e. $3$ is idempotent in $\Bbb Z_6)$ I'd recommend adding a remark so as not to mislead readers.

Comment: Ah, good to have you back, @Bill, I missed you.

Answer (score 2):

In a ring in general the definitions are not the same;  being prime is rather the stronger property, this is literally true when there are no zero-divisors. (Note that the definition of irreducible needs to be modified a bit to account for invertible elements other than $1$.)

Consider for example the ring of polynomials without linear term, that is polynomials of the form:

$$a_0 + a_2X^2 + a_3X^3 + \dots + a_nX^n$$

In this structure $X^2$ is irreducible, yet not prime since $X^2$ divides $X^3 \times X^3$ yet not $X^3$.

However, the definitions are equivalent in a principal ideal domain or more generally in a unique factorization domain, or in even more general structures.

Since the integers are such a domain, the definitions are equivalent *in that context.*

---

You can also construct examples in the integers by restricting to sub-semigroups. For example if you consider only the positive integers whose decimal digit expansion end in $1$, then this is a multiplicative subsemigroup with identity.

In that structure $21$ is irreducible, yet not prime: $21$ divides $81 \times 2401$, the numbers on the right being $3^4$ and $7^4$ respectively.

Answer (score 1):

In a domain, every prime is irreducible.
A standard example that the converse does not always hold is
$$
3 \cdot 3 = 9 = (2+\sqrt{-5})(2-\sqrt{-5})
$$
in the ring $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$. Then $3$ and $2\pm\sqrt{-5}$ are irreducible but not prime.