# Show that the two definitions of prime are equivalent.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let us define primes in $\mathbb Z$ as follows:

**Def$1$** $p>1$ is said to be a prime if only positive divisors of $p$ are $1$ and $p$.

**Def$2$** A natural number $p>1$ is said to be a prime if $p|ab\implies p|a $ or $p|b$.

I want to show these definitions are equivalent.But I have no clue how to proceed.Can someone show me a way out?$(1)\implies (2)$ is easy but what about the converse?

Comment: What is expected is that you *assume* one as a definition, and proceed to *derive* the other as a property. Then switch which one is assumed and do the other proof. [details on steps are in many number theory books.]

Comment: @KishalaySarkar:  Have you checked Burton's elementary number theory book?  I remember seeing something along these lines there before.

Comment: Suppose that $p = r \times s ~: ~r,s \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}.$  Can you think of specific values for $a,b$ such that $p ~| ~(a \times b)~$ and yet $p$ does not divide either $a$ or $b$?

Comment: @user2661923 if we consider $r,s$ to be prime, and let's consider $a$ has $r$ in prime factorisation but not $s$ and b has $s$ in prime factorisation but not $r$,so $p|a \times b$ and $p\nmid a$ ,$p\nmid b$.am I correct?

Comment: @user69608 Re-examine my last comment.  Irrelevant whether $r,s$ prime.  The comment, as is, suggests specific values for $a,b$ directly in terms of $r,s$ such that $p ~| ~(a\times b)$ and $p$ does not divide either $a$ or $b$.

Comment: Related [The relation between irreducible and primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2945567/152568).