# Applications of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$

Tags: number-theory, popular-math

I am willing to give a general audience lecture about prime factorization, and opening towards the lack of unique factorization in the case of e.g. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$. However, I have two issues :

- how to introduce $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ naturally (for general audience or high-schoolers)? They don't have naturally complex numbers, but maybe I can stay murky about it, or say it is the least we can do to solve $x^2-5=0$ (why is this equation important, though?)
- are there nice, yet accessible, applications (e.g. geometrically, or in cryptography, etc.) of the unique factorization in such fields?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ is a field and hence a UFD :)

Comment: If forced to talk $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$ specifically, I would make it a story about the golden ration $\phi=(1+\sqrt5)/2$ and think of $K=\Bbb{Q}(\phi)$ instead. Then you still have unique factorization in $\Bbb{Z}[\phi]$. But the units of the ring are $\pm\phi^n,n\in\Bbb{Z}$. Applications? After you have given the audience their fill of the golden ratio, you can mention [how it is used in WLAN standard](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4283077_Applications_of_the_Golden_Code).

Comment: [This](https://ecse.monash.edu/staff/eviterbo/perfect_codes/Golden_Code.html) may be a better source for Golden code. Emanuele chose to denote it by $\theta$ instead :-)

Comment: Note that ${\bf Z}[\sqrt5]$ is not the ring of integers of ${\bf Q}[\sqrt5]$. If you want an example where ${\bf Z}[\sqrt d]$ is the ring of integers of ${\bf Q}[\sqrt d]$, then you might want to use $d=2$ (with unique factorization), or $d=6$ (without unique factorization).

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would do it.

- Explain what it meant to be [prime or irreducible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2945567/the-relation-between-irreducible-and-primes).
- Tell them, preferably with a justification, that there are numbers, such as $\sqrt2, \sqrt3, \cdots$, that are not rational. But be cautious not to go beyond positive square roots.
- That gives you a way to expand the horizon by adding these extra numbers, one at a time. Like $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt2], \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt2],$
  Also, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt6]\subset\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt2][\sqrt3]$ while $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt6]=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt2][\sqrt3]$
- Tell them, while this gives you some extra freedom (I would show them that $\mathbb{Q}[\Delta]$ is where the solutions of a rational quadratic equation with discriminant $\Delta$ lives or casually mention [something like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27s_cattle_problem#Pell_equation)), sometimes you lose some nice algebraic properties. For example $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt5]$ is not a unique factorization domain. $$(3-\sqrt5)(3+\sqrt5)=2^2$$

I wouldn't talk about complex numbers or Gaussian integers at all. Later when they see complex numbers, they will remember your talk.

Comment: ${\bf Z}[\sqrt2][\sqrt3]$ is **not** ${\bf Z}[\sqrt6]$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thanks for the corrections. I shouldn't have done that careless edit.

Comment: Nice points! However, what about, for example, solving actual equations? For example, to find all the integer solutions of some equation, you interpret the equation over $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 5]$ instead of $\mathbb Q$ and use some properties? I mean, isn't that the reason we invent field extensions after all?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you choosing this specific topic of $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{5})$, which really sounds like it is about $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{5}]$?  Students are going to find the notation intimidating.

And is the audience high school students or a true general audience?  If it's a general audience, then your topic is too sophisticated.  Find something simpler, like puzzles (15-puzzle, Rubik's cube).

If the audience is high school students who have already taken algebra and trigonometry, and if the goal is to discuss a setting where there is failure of unique factorization, then use an example they already know but had not thought much about: the system of trigonometric polynomials, which are things like the function
$$
\sin^2(x)\cos^3(x) - 4\sin(x)\cos^2(x) + 2\cos(x) - 9.
$$
It's a polynomial in $\sin x$ and $\cos x$.  You can add and multiply such functions, and thanks to $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$ you can write the same expression in multiple ways.  In fancier language, these are precisely the finite Fourier series (linear combinations of $\sin(mx)\cos(nx)$ for $m, n \geq 0$), but you don't have to mention that.

Anyway, it turns out that $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are irreducible: they're not the product of two other nonconstant trigonometric polynomials. And also $1 \pm \sin x$ and $1 \pm \cos x$ are irreducible.  This implies that the familiar relation from trigonometry
$$
\sin^2 x = 1 - \cos^2 x = (1+\cos x)(1 - \cos x)
$$
is an example of nonunique irreducible factorization: $1 + \cos x$ and $1 - \cos x$ are not scale multiples of $\sin x$ (why? neither of the functions $1 + \cos x$ and $1 - \cos x$ vanish at all the values where $\sin x = 0$, so $1\pm \cos x$ isn't a scalar multiple of $\sin x$).  Here is Hale Trotter's short paper about this example: [http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/trotter.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/trotter.pdf).