# Is $x$ irreducible in $(\mathbb Z/{12\mathbb Z})[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I have a couple of doubts regarding irreducibility of $x$ over $Z/{12Z}$.

First is w.r.t definition of irreducibility :

When we talk of a polynomial $p(x)$ being irreducible in $Z_{n}$, we basically mean to say that $p(x)=0$ has no solutions in $Z_{n}$ right?

If so then $x$ is not irreducible in $Z_{n}$.

I arrived at this result by showing that $A=(x)$ the ideal generated by $x$ is not maximal by proving that $Z_{12}[x]/A$ is not a field.

My attempt is as follows:

The elements of $Z_{12}[x]/(x)$ are of the form $c+A$ where $c \in Z_{12}$. But since $Z_{12}$ is not a field, $c^{-1}$ might not exist. Hence $Z_{12}[x]/(x)$ is not a field thus $x$ is not irreducible over $Z_{12}$.

Could someone check whether my attempts are right?

EDIT:

I know that a polynomial $p\in R[x]$ is said to be irreducible if it cannot be factored into the product of polynomials $f,g \in R[x]$ such that one of them is a constant.

Comment: "irreducible" is not the same as "no roots".  Linear polynomials, over $\mathbb Z$ say,  have roots but are irreducible.  $(x^2+1)(x^2+2)$ has no roots but it is not irreducible.

Comment: irreducible means having no factors right? Doesn't it essentially translate into not having roots?

Comment: No.  I added counterexamples in both directions.

Comment: @Ananthakrishna They are related, sure. They are not, however, the same thing.

Comment: Did you mean irreducible in $(\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z)[x]$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes

Comment: @lulu oh, i see

Comment: So when can the mean the same?

Comment: quadratic polynomials over $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner , okay! but is the approach taken by me in showing that $x$ is not irreducible is correct ?

Comment: @Ananthakrishna your approach is good and you can generalize it to any non ID ring $R[x]/(x) = R$ so $(x)$ is not maximal ideal so $x$ is reducible.

Comment: @AmerYR Thanks!

Comment: You should state which definition of "irreducible" and "associate" you are using since they bifurcate into inequivalent notions in rings with zero divisors, e.g. [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/881819/242)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Irreducible means the following: we say that $r\in R $ is *irreducible* if $r = ab $ then either $a$ or $b$ is a unit. So in $\mathbb Z_{12}$, for example, $2$ is irreducible but $3$ is not since $3 = 3(-3) \mod 12 $ in general we have $p\mid n $ is reducible iff $p^2 \nmid n$.

So let's return to our ring $\mathbb{Z}_{12}[x]$ and consider $x=(3x+4 )(4x+3)= 12x^2 + 25x + 12 \bmod 12 $ hence $x$ is reducible (if we proved the factors are non units) as you said. Now we need to show that $3x+4$ and $4x+3$ are not units in $\mathbb{Z}_{12} [x]$.

You can  show that $3x+4$ is a not a unit by contradiction.

Comment: **Beware** $ $ There is no *standard* definition of "irreducible", "associate" etc. in rings with *zero divisors*, e.g. [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/881819/242)

Comment: Note that the above factorization of $x$ has already been mentioned here many  times in the past, e.g. five years ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/732005/242), which includes citations on expositions on factorization theory in non-domains.